# How does the height of a UITableViewCell get set

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uitableview

I know that when UIKit renders a cell, it uses `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to calculate  the height.  My question is, how and when does that get set on the actual `UITableViewCell`.  I want to build dynamic cells and will need to calculate the placement of text within the cell.  I believe I can just use self.bounds and self.frame - I was just curious about at what point those are set - even with the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you return the cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the tableview sets a number of properties, including the bounds of the cell, then calls `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. The only modifications after that call are setting alpha/frame, and even then only when animating the row.

Given that, if you're using a stock `UITableViewCell`, you can layout your text in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and be assured that the cell already has the correct width/height. That said, if you're doing anything more than just the basics, you may want to consider subclassing `UITableViewCell`. In your subclass, you can lay out your fields in `layoutSubviews` and be assured that your cell will always be laid out correctly.

Comment: My goal is to draw the contents of my cell using drawRect, so I will be subclassing UITableViewCell.  Should I be calling setNeedsDisplay in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:, or should I be calling it from the UiTableViewCell's layoutSubviews?  Is there documentation that outlines the flow so I can see how to best do this?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate, like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat result;
    result = 120.0f;
    return result;
}
```

The above example will set any cell hat is created in the `canEditRowAtIndexPath` delegate.

You can alternatively use section and row values to determine which cell / sections the height is set.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am interested in at what point the UITableViewCell knows it's height - not where I tell the UITableViewController what the height of the cell should be.

Comment: return cell, thats the point the UITableView looks for the cellHeight.

Comment: I guess I should be asking, at what point does my UITableViewCell know it's height so I can call [UITableViewCell setNeedsDisplay]?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend custom cell

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//You need to do your calculation for 
[super drawRect:rect];
}
```

You need to do your calculation to make it appear in the proper location of cell in drawRect.

Comment: Not only is this not what he asked, but this won't even work if the cell has a background view (as grouped tableview cells do).