# get UITableViewCell's height after setting height for each UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios

I set height for each UITableViewCell in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I need to get each UITableViewCell's height in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

because I need to addSubView in different cells.

I've tried to use `cell.frame` & `cell.bounds` & `cell.contentView.frame`, but the height hasn't changed.

Comment: you can use global variable and use same variable in heightForRowAtIndexPath function, as well as cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: cell.bounds.size.height  will give you height.have tried like this ?

Comment: @V-Xtreme I've tried cell.bounds.size.height,it does't work.Like the first answer said, they are different stuffs.

Comment: @satgi no.. the point is that the cell's frame isnt final until/right before it is onscreen. see my answer for the correct way

Answer (score 8):

This may be too late, but you can use the delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect cellSize = cell.frame;
}
```

Hope it helps anyone, Let me know if I missed out something. :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this way:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // create object
    id myObj = [_arrayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // create static identifier
    static NSString * myIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // create static UITableViewCell
    static UITableViewCell * cell;

    // create cell with object
    cell = [self buildCell:myIdentifier tableView:tableView obj: myObj];

    return cell.contentView.frame.size.height;

}
```

Comment: You don't have a guarantee that the content has been layout out and therefore, has the appropriate size...

Answer (score 2):

What about `UITableView`s method, `- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Get the rect like this,

```
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

They are different stuffs. In heightForRowAtIndexPath: you tell the UITableView how much vertical space it shoud use to show the corresponding cell, but this don't affect the actual size of the cell! So if you want them to match you have to manually set the dimensions.

If you don't want / need to resize the cell frame you should simply store the height in a property of your custom cell class.

Comment: by default the cellFrame is set to the height you return... !? If never resized a cell frame manually

Comment: @Daij-Djan maybe I don't understand your comment, but the cell frame is not set! you can easily check this in debug... actually I used this behavior to get some nice effects in tableviews: imagine a transparent table with cellheight bigger than cellsize.

Comment: you do, sorry for the bad english there! Ill try it now.... it would be news for me though .

Comment: - (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
} => the cells frame is resized to fill the height given, so I dont get it...

Comment: @Daij-Djan I see the misunderstanding: in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method that satgi and me where using you don't have the frame set according to the heightForRowAtIndexPath value, while you was referring to layoutSubviews. Also if you create the cell bigger than heightForRowAtIndexPath value you'll see them overlapping.

Comment: sure you dont. it wont be set as it isnt on screen and true for the second too. frames are 'rubish' before the view is actually added

Comment: I found that maybe i could custom my cell in  `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`,cell's frame has been set in this method,from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631781/how-does-the-height-of-a-uitableviewcell-get-set)

Answer (score -1):

As @ilMalvagioDottorProsci says,The value returned by the heightForRowAtIndexPath function do not affect the actual size of the cell.

If you want achieve that each row height is determined by the cell height.I have a trick.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id aKey = [self buildCellCacheKey:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([_cellCache objectForKey:aKey]==nil) {
        [_cellCache setObject:cell forKey:aKey];
    }

    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // for flexible height of table view cell.in this way,the cell height won't be caculate twice.
    id aKey = [self buildCellCacheKey:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cacheCell = [_cellCache objectForKey:aKey];
    if (cacheCell) {
        [cacheCell retain];
        [_cellCache removeObjectForKey:aKey];
        LOGDebug(@"return cache cell [%d]",indexPath.row);
        return [cacheCell autorelease];
    }

// here is the code you can config your cell..  
}
```

Comment: this works and for simple tables with only a few items it is cool but it is quite bad for larger tables as I see it. every cell gets instantiated just because its height is requested -> a) a lot of views are made and b) you 'disable' cell reusing.

Comment: Oh,I see....you are right.I use this trick in my code.Do you have any suggestion how I should fix this?@Daij-Djan

Comment: I would really go with what I suggested.... override layoutSubviews of cell if you need to work with the frames and bounds. .. that also furthers SOC by moving layouting code away from the viewController and into the cell

Comment: I mean If I want that the heightForRowAtIndexPath function returned value is as same as the cell height and I want to write the calculate code in the cell's .m file,not calculate it in the tableview delegate and cache it.

Comment: what I always do is have a static method [MyCellClass calculatedHeightForCellValue:(id)theModelObjectToBeDisplayed]; => it doesnt create any views or so just does calculation on how big the cell should become

Comment: e.g.: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/TwitterSearchExampleApp/blob/master/TwitterSearch/DDTweetTableViewCell.m

Comment: dont know... thats only what _I_ deeem best -- n o guarantees. as I said: for smaller tables your trick is neat